# What is the stable and latest version of .Net Framework we can use in WPF Application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5, .net-framework-version

I want to upgrade my live WPF Application's .Net Framework.

Which is the stable and latest version in .Net Framework ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It gets upgraded without your involvement, programmers are not very good at getting it right.  Windows Update gets that job done, I think it currently deploys 4.7.1 to all machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, the latest version of the full .NET framework is version 4.7.2. You can find the latest SDK and runtime downloads [here on the Microsoft download website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows) and install what you need.

Comment: Why would the OP care about .NET Core when WPF does not exist in .NET Core?

Comment: I've edited the answer to remove the reference to .NET Core

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is a nice iniciative of you to upgrade the .Net of your WPF Application.

Right now, as 20 June,2018, it is .NET Framework 4.7.2 and it can be downloaded at

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

This month they released .NET Framework 4.8 Early Access build 3621

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/06/06/announcing-net-framework-4-8-early-access-build-3621/

Also it was announced earlier that .Net Core 3 will support for Windows Desktop, namely: WPF, Windows Forms and UWP

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/

Note: To do this upgrade, on my projects, on the most cases it was just a matter of installing the newest Net Framework SDK, set the target in Project settings and rebuild the App in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: With over 6k reputation, you should know already that requests for off-site resources are off-topic. Specially when the answer will change over time so much

Comment: User just asked what is the current version. That is a fair question in the middle of so much information after BUILD 2018. I answered and also put the future planned versions. Down vote unecessary. Just needed to move the question to superuser.com

Comment: Worse than that is to have those people who down votes for answering the right thing, about a relevant topic in a programming site.

Comment: This would also be off-topic in Super User, since the question asks for the current latest version and that makes no sense. Just google ".net framework latest version" and be done with it, we don't need to maintain answers to link to the official documentation